# Scala: List of vectors to Unique List of items in immutable way

Tags: scala, list, functional-programming, immutability

I am receiving list of vectors from some function like

```
(List(Vector(1), Vector(1, 2), Vector(1, 3), Vector(1, 2, 4), Vector(1, 5)))
```

I want to convert it into distinct values of integers like

```
List(1,2,3,4,5)
```

in Scala using complete immutability.

Please suggest what are the efficient ways to achieve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `flatten` and `distinct` methods on `List`.

```
val list = List(Vector(1), 
                Vector(1, 2), 
                Vector(1, 3), 
                Vector(1, 2, 4), 
                Vector(1, 5))

val flattened = list.flatten // Gives List(1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 5)

val distinct = flattened.distinct // Gives List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is alternate solution.

```
val lst = (List(Vector(1), Vector(1, 2), Vector(1, 3), Vector(1, 2, 4), Vector(1, 5)))

lst.flatten.toSet.toList

List[Int] = List(5, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```